# Not able to read from Firebase Database

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

here is my code

```
Future<void> fetchDataAndStoreLocally() async {
    debugPrint("fetchDataAndStoreLocally");
    final firebaseApp = Firebase.app();
    final rtdb = FirebaseDatabase.instanceFor(app: firebaseApp, databaseURL: NetworkClient.fb_rdb_api);
    final ref = rtdb.ref();
    final snapshot = await ref.child(NetworkClient.fb_rdb_sync_child).get();
    if(snapshot.exists){
      debugPrint("Line4_exists");
    }else{
      debugPrint("Line4_does_not_exists");
    }
}
```

the code is just stuck at this line

```
final snapshot = await ref.child(NetworkClient.fb_rdb_sync_child).get();
```

the problem is that it doesn't goes to next line. Even if I put it inside try catch block I get no error. I have tried a lot of solutions but nothing seems to work out.

Comment: can you add your db ss